# Cocoapods error

Tags: cocoapods

From my Podfile: why does this work:

`pod 'RestKit', :git => 'git@github.com:EATechnologies/RestKit.git', :commit => '56401aaa5b3714bbde5d2852f92c0b29e392b460'`

but this does not:

`pod 'RestKit', :git => 'git@github.com:EATechnologies/RestKit.git', :commit => '0831f2dc2da01731d37795a2c3bd8acb4045dda9'`

When I use the latter, I get an error that looks like this:

```
$pod update
Updating spec repo `master'
-> Pre-downloading: 'MCSMKeychainItem'
-> Pre-downloading: 'RestKit'
[!] Failed: /usr/bin/git rev-list --max-count=1 0831f2dc2da01731d37795a2c3bd8acb4045dda9
[!] Failed: /usr/bin/git rev-list --max-count=1 0831f2dc2da01731d37795a2c3bd8acb4045dda9
[!] Cache unable to find git reference `0831f2dc2da01731d37795a2c3bd8acb4045dda9' for `git@github.com:EATechnologies/RestKit.git'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed with Cocoapods 0.15.1.

Answer (score 0):

1 - first install git (command line tool for mac)

link to download is : http://git-scm.com/download/mac

2 - then open commind line (or terminal) and type 
$ sudo gem install cocoapods     (you need to wait here , be patient)

3 - now you can shoot the command "pod --version" to check the version of the pod you just installed.

4 - shoot again pod search libpusher (just an example of a library, you can type any library name here instead of 'libpusher' ).

5- let it be complete , it may take some time.

6- then most imp step , create the pod file , (name can be 'podfile') in your project directory and add it to your project in Xcode.

7 - Now Here the secret is : you need to provide the path to this pod file too here , so type command:

```
cd /Rakesh/vidyo_demo/vidyo_phonegap/ios  (eg.)
```

after cd command rest is the path of the pod file directory.

8- and now when you will type 'pod install ' command in terminal. 
and all libraries (which are written in podfile) will get installed on your project path. just then open the project which now has a workspace file. like demo.xcworkspace (open it)

9- here is the format of pod file:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'libPusher', '~> 1.4'
```

[image]